# Escape from ampersand in batch variables

Tags: batch-file, escaping, ampersand

I'm trying to put together a complex batch script that does multiple things at once.  I'm getting hung on one portion of it.
I want the script to ask for a customer number then place that number in a specific spot in a URL.
The problem is that the URL has an ampersand and when I echo the variable contents it gives an error.

```
@echo off
set /p id="Enter ID: "
set URL=https://firsturlsectionhere.com
set FULLURL=%URL%id%^&therestofurl
@echo %FULLURL%
```

Any help you guys could give would be great.

Comment: Just use a url shortener. It is what I do for a script that downloads print drivers from URLs with ampersands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your variable with quotes then you do not need to escape the ampersand. But because you have the ampersand you need to echo the variable with delayed expansion.

```
 @echo off
 set /p id="Enter ID: "
 set URL=https://firsturlsectionhere.com
 set "FULLURL=%URL%/%id%&therestofurl"
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 echo !FULLURL!
 endlocal
 pause
```

If you keep the escape character in the variable and quote surround your set command then you can echo the variable as is.

```
 @echo off
 set /p id="Enter ID: "
 set URL=https://firsturlsectionhere.com
 set "FULLURL=%URL%/%id%^&therestofurl"
 echo %FULLURL%
 pause
```